# Converter only firing once and not every time label content changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ivalueconverter

I have label with a width of auto, that is bound to a property of type string.

```
<Label x:Name="ExampleLabel" Content="{Binding ExampleProperty}"Height="30" Width="Auto" >
```

I then have a property that is bound to the width of that label. The converter should convert the width to a negative value.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <c:PositiveToNegativeConverter x:Key="PositiveToNegativeConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

"{Binding ElementName=ExampleLabel, Path=Width, Converter={StaticResource PositiveToNegativeConverter}}"
```

I want the converter to execute when the label content changes, but it is only fired once, when the application loads.

Here is my converter

```
public class PositiveToNegativeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value * -1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Math.Abs((double) value);
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you bind to `ActualWidth` instead of `Width`? `Width` is the design time value, `ActualWidth` is the live-updated runtime value.

Comment: It does. Thanks man. I didn't know about actualwidth :)

Comment: Cool, I'll make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you bind to [`ActualWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [`Width`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width(v=vs.110).aspx)? `Width` is just whatever value *you* last assigned to the `Width` property, while `ActualWidth` is a read-only live-updated runtime value for how wide the thing really is in the UI.

I would expect this to update when you want it to:

```
"{Binding ElementName=ExampleLabel, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource PositiveToNegativeConverter}}"
```